# Speed up Hash Match operator on one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-performance

I have one temp table with 1 million rows, and i just need to go through all the rows and do some basic scalar computation, something like this:

```
SELECT m.BatteryID, m.CarID, /*calculating some scalar*/
FROM #Return m 
GROUP BY m.CarID, m.YearTime, m.BatteryID;
```

The table has one identity 1,1 Clustered indexed PK.

The query plan looks like this:
[image]

It shows that i have a clustered index scan which is fine, since i always use all rows from the table, hence the tree is traveled from top to bottom.
Also, not the clustered index scan is the most time consuming (17%), but the Hash Match (65%)
Is there any way to improve the performance on such simple scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try adding an index on `CarId, YearTime, BatteryId`.

Comment: A columnstore index would provide 10-100x speedup here.

Comment: @usr yes, but columnstore index is not in sql2008

Comment: @GordonLinoff Brilliant, now it becomes 8% StreamAggregate and 90% Clustered Index scan. I tried it before but the opposite order of the composite key. Why CarID first?

Comment: @Avithohol . . . Hmmm, I wouldn't think that the order of the three columns would make a difference.  I just put it first because that is the order in the `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for the answer. I mark your comments as solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why not add your answer as an actual answer, below? StackOverflow still treats this question as unanswered.

Comment: @Avithohol . . . I cannot explain why SQL Server would have different execution plans for different orderings of the keys in the index.  My suggestion could have been for any arbitrary permutation of the three keys in an index.  Because I don't know why different permutations result in different query plans, I can't really explain why it works, and I'm leaving the comment, but not providing it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding index as (CarId, YearTime, BatteryId), it becomes 8% StreamAggregate and 90% Clustered Index scan.
Thanks Gordon